# I want to correlate a specific ID that has a draft status in LoadRunner, but it has a dynamic left boundary

Tags: performance, testing, scripting, correlation, loadrunner

Hi fellow IT professionals, i want to correlate a specific **CustomerSimId** "2645190" that has a **Status** "draft". However it has a very lengthy and dynamic Left Boundary. May I know how to do it if it is possible?

```
{"Name":"TAWWRBXV JRHMQTAW JKA OCK","CustomerId":244498,"BRN":"829636H","ParentGroupId":337585,"ParentGroupName":"TAWWRBXV JRHMQTAW JKA OCK","SubGroupId":null,"SubGroupName":null,"ARMID":"","ARMAvatarFileId":null,"CompanyAvatarFileId":null,"StatusId":1,"Status":"Draft","SimulationDescription":"Simulation created at 03/02/2023 10:43:28 AM","ModifiedDateTime":"\/Date(1675392279607)\/","ModifiedBy":"Armini @ Arni binti Mohd Ismail","CreatedDateTime":"\/Date(1675392208433)\/","CreatedBy":"Armini @ Arni binti Mohd Ismail","PublishedDate":null,"PublishedDateLong":null,"RolledUpBy":"Armini @ Arni binti Mohd Ismail","RollUpUserAvatarFileId":null,"ActualDataDateTime":"31/03/2022","CustomerSimId":2645186,"IsLatestRolledUp":false,"IsLatestRolledUpRejected":false,"IsActualCustomer":true,"IsBorrower":true,"OvlGroupId":343135,"OriginCountryId":1,"OriginCountry":"MY"},

{"Name":"TAWWRBXV JRHMQTAW JKA OCK","CustomerId":244498,"BRN":"829636H","ParentGroupId":337585,"ParentGroupName":"TAWWRBXV JRHMQTAW JKA OCK","SubGroupId":null,"SubGroupName":null,"ARMID":"","ARMAvatarFileId":null,"CompanyAvatarFileId":null,"StatusId":5,"Status":"Completed","SimulationDescription":"Simulation created at 03/02/2023 11:22:46 AM","ModifiedDateTime":"\/Date(1675703790610)\/","ModifiedBy":"Mohd Shamsul Irwan bin Ab Wahab","CreatedDateTime":"\/Date(1675394566980)\/","CreatedBy":"Armini @ Arni binti Mohd Ismail","PublishedDate":"03/02/2023 11:41 AM","PublishedDateLong":"03/02/2023 11:41:02 AM","RolledUpBy":"Mohd Shamsul Irwan bin Ab Wahab","RollUpUserAvatarFileId":null,"ActualDataDateTime":"31/03/2022","CustomerSimId":2645188,"IsLatestRolledUp":false,"IsLatestRolledUpRejected":false,"IsActualCustomer":true,"IsBorrower":true,"OvlGroupId":343135,"OriginCountryId":1,"OriginCountry":"MY"},

{"Name":"TAWWRBXV JRHMQTAW JKA OCK","CustomerId":244498,"BRN":"829636H","ParentGroupId":337585,"ParentGroupName":"TAWWRBXV JRHMQTAW JKA OCK","SubGroupId":null,"SubGroupName":null,"ARMID":"","ARMAvatarFileId":null,"CompanyAvatarFileId":null,"StatusId":1,**"Status":"Draft"**,"SimulationDescription":"Simulation created at 03/02/2023 03:32:56 PM","ModifiedDateTime":"\/Date(1675409653153)\/","ModifiedBy":"Armini @ Arni binti Mohd Ismail","CreatedDateTime":"\/Date(1675409576637)\/","CreatedBy":"Armini @ Arni binti Mohd Ismail","PublishedDate":null,"PublishedDateLong":null,"RolledUpBy":"Armini @ Arni binti Mohd Ismail","RollUpUserAvatarFileId":null,"ActualDataDateTime":"31/03/2022","CustomerSimId":**2645190**,"IsLatestRolledUp":false,"IsLatestRolledUpRejected":false,"IsActualCustomer":true,"IsBorrower":true,"OvlGroupId":343135,"OriginCountryId":1,"OriginCountry":"MY"},
```

I tried to do a negative value SaveLen=-8 - which it did not work. Appreciate if there are advice for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use regular expression; if you want to capture CustomerSimId from third line which has status draft and CustomerSimId followed by **and digits then you can try below regular expression and use loadrunner web_reg_save_param_regexp function . Something like this

Regex -- > Status":"Draft"(.*)CustomerSimId":[\\*]+[0-9]*

web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=CustomerSimId_correlation",
"RegExp=Status\":\"Draft"(.*)CustomerSimId\":[\\*]+[0-9]*",
SEARCH_FILTERS,
"Scope=ALL ",
"Ordinal=1",
"Group=3",
LAST);

and if you want to capture "CustomerSimId":2645186 (from line 1) where it doesn't have * you can try regex - Status\":\"Draft\"(.*)CustomerSimId\":[0-9]+ and use Group 2 in web_reg_save_param_regexp function

Function reference - https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/2023-2023-r1/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/web/lrFr_web_reg_save_param_regexp.htm